# How to deal with LVM RAID mismatches – are there benign causes?

Tags: raid, software-raid, lvm, raid-1

I employ LVM with raid1 volumes both at home and at work. One of the disks in my home server has been starting to report S.M.A.R.T. selftest read failures. Looking for ways to investigate the severity of the problem, I found `lvchange --syncaction check`, which (unsurprisingly) found mismatches in one of the volumes spanning that disk and also caused I/O errors to be reported by the kernel. So I moved that side of the mirror to a different disk and assumed that the error-free disk had correct data.

But it also found mismatches in other volumes that didn't have I/O errors, including one that doesn't span the disk in question, as well as some of the volumes on the server at work, which I find concerning, since there's no way to know which side of the mirror is correct. We're talking 20736 blocks with mismatches over one 155 GiB volume, 32640 mismatches over one 1.2 TiB volume, 6912 over one 47 GiB volume, and 256 across an 18.6 GiB one.

1. Is it common to see such numbers? Some of the disks have been running for around 5 years, others for only a couple, under not that heavy load, I'd say. Are there situations where it's normal for mismatches to arise (without a crash), say if a file is written to and then deleted before the changes are fully written to disk, can the write operation be aborted? I found one mention of mirrored swap, but that's not relevant here.
2. Are there any tools for pinpointing which files (or even filesystem metadata) may be affected? Just the number of mismatches isn't very helpful. I can think of one method, namely marking one PV in a mirror as write-mostly, making a copy of the entire file system, then marking the other PV as write-mostly instead and comparing (avoiding making changes in the meantime), but that seems quite cumbersome.
3. It could be that many (or even all) of the mismatches are in unallocated space. I could write to all that space to force those blocks to be synchronized and see if the number of mismatches goes down. Any other suggestions?
4. Should I just run `lvchange --syncaction repair`, hope for the best, and then activate `--raidintegrity`? I haven't noticed any filesystem or data corruption yet; can I expect that the data I see is the data that will be re-synced?